# SQL Server 2016 Service pack 1 not updating version after installation

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016

I have installed `SQL Server 2016` in my `Windows Server 2016` machine successfully. I am trying to install service pack 1 for the server and I downloaded the file from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276

But when I check the current version from registry in the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.INSTANCE_NAME\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion` it is still showing `13.0.1601.5` instead of `13.0.4001.0`.

I am installing in Command prompt using the command `SQLServer2016SP1-KB3182545-x64-ENU.exe /QUIETSIMPLE /INSTANCENAME=INSTANCE_NAME /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`.

The `summary.txt` file after the update is showing me the following message.

```
Final result:                  The patch installer has failed to update the shared features. To determine the reason for failure, review the log files.
Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643838
Start time:                    2018-04-12 11:33:15
End time:                      2018-04-12 11:34:06
```

I could not find and specific log in the `Log file Viewer` for the time specified in the `summary.txt` file.

Comment: What is returned from `PRINT @@VERSION;` on the SQL Server? Have you tried running the installer outside of command prompt (as in using the GUI)?

Comment: The output is `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU8) (KB4077064) - 13.0.4474.0 (X64)   Feb 24 2018 13:53:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Then you already have SP1 installed. :)

Comment: The problem is I am checking the version installed using the Registry path I have mentioned in the question. It is not updated to `13.0.4001.0`.

Comment: I can't answer that question, however, the best way to check the version of SQL Server is to do so in SQL Server (using `@@VERSION`). Registry keys can be altered. The reason, however, that your install is failing is now obvious; you're trying to install SP1, when you already have SP1 CU8 installed.

Comment: No, I installed the SP1 first and I saw only the old version number. So I ran SP1 CU8 afterwards thinking that might change the version. But still the same version is what I see in Registry. I got the same error code when I first installed only SP1 (Without CU8)

Comment: Like i said, I woulnd't use the registry to check the version.

Comment: My bad. I use the Registry to check the versions of SQL Server 2012 and 2014 and it works perfectly. Only with 2016 version I am facing this problem.